# Add in escape char after a yield

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to prompt a user to enter in two numbers and print the result.

```
def add():
    while True:
        x = yield "x=_\x08"
        y = yield "y=_\x08"
        print (x+y)
```

I can do something like `input('_\x08')` so that the cursor looks like:

```
|_
```

But with the `yield` it just prints the chars literally:

```
'x=_\x08'
```

Is there a way to escape on those?

Comment: How do you call the function?

Comment: It _doesn't_ print those characters literally. If you're in a REPL environment, then yes, doing `x = add(); next(x)` will cause the `__repr__()` of the result of `next` to be printed. If you do `print(next(x))`, as you should when wanting to print something, then it prints what you expect it to print

Comment: @Chris_Rands see the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that in a `yield` you do not receive something like a prompt to send in the values, and need to do it manually with a `.send` event. For example:

```
def add():
    while True:
        x = yield "x="
        y = yield "y="
        print (x+y)

x=add()
next(x)
# 'x='
x.send(2)
# 'y='
x.send(3)
# 5
...
```

So even if the `\8` backspace were to work, there wouldn't be a cursor that is visible or active to work on it with.